# Storing a URL that your app points to externally, so URL be changed anytime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, afnetworking, parse-platform

I have a UIImageView - `*bannerImageView` in my application which makes use of **AFNetworking**'s convenient **`- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:`** method.

To prepare for usage of this method, I have to create an `NSURLRequest` object as follows:

`NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.images.com/image.png"]];`

---

**QUESTION:**

Is there a way that I can store this url *(I'm thinking in a text file?)* somewhere online, that my app will always point to to look for a URL to request?

Reason being that due to certain cirumstances of the project I'm developing for, I will need to change the image's URL in future rather frequently and it doesn't make sense to have to push a whole app update just for this purpose.

---

P.S. In my `- (void)viewDidLoad`, I have a line of code that starts the *networkActivityIndicator* - `[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;`. Is there a better place for me to insert this code rather than to start the *networkActivityIndicator* each time the view loads, and only stop it in the success block of the **`- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:`** method?

---

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a rather simple way of achieving this with the help of a mobile BaaS (Backend as a Service). I have decided to use [Parse](https://www.parse.com/).

Out of the many features available there, I have used the data browser the following is an example of what I've done:

1. Created a class called *`Advertisement`*
2. Created a string column called *`AdURL`* *(and whatever information I need that is relevant to that object e.g. AdName or AdImage etc. with its respective data type)*.
3. Inserted the URL value into the *`AdURL`* column.
4. Hit enter, and a new object (row) will be created. The object will have a unique ObjectID that will automatically be generated for you.
5. Now, I just have to integrate the Parse SDK into my project and the query whatever class'es objects/value(s) that I have created above with its respective ObjectID.

In future, if I ever need to change the value (in this case, the URL that will be opened in Safari when the user taps a UIButton), I just have to go back to Parse's data browser to change that particular value, and the changes will be reflected immediately as each time the app needs to look for that value, it creates a new query to that class, object, and value of the specified column.

Here is an example of the query code in my app:

```
- (IBAction)bannerBtnTapped:(id)sender
{
    // Create PFQuery object.
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EXAMPLECLASS"];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"EXAMPLEOBJECTID" block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)
     {
         // "object" will be the row that is returned according to your specified class and ObjectID. Assigned the returned value to an NSURL var "*url"
         NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:object[@"EXAMPLECOLUMNNAME"]];

         // Open the url in Safari.
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
     }];
}
```

Hope this simple solution helps somebody in future!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, the logo has to be changed globally for all users. If so, and if you have full control on server side you have two options:

- using php or whatever server side language, create a very minimal proxy that transparently map a generic image name to the proper resource, this require little or no code on iOS side, and more on server side. For minimal proxy, I mean, you call a resource, let's say http://www.yourserver.com/imagelocator.php which is retrieving your image in background, and then serve it to your client by setting the appropriate header. You need to write a few lines of code, depending on the server side language used.
- implement a 307 redirect, and manage that with iOS, this require little code on server side, and more code on iOS side. This is similiar to your solution about txt file, but is more elegant in my opinion. If you have apache you can create an .htaccess file with all the rule you need. If you have a look at iOS NSURLConnection you will see that by interpreting the HTTP status code, you can handle a redirection. In this case if iOS ask for http://www.yourserver.com/logo.png the server itself is responding with the new address http://www.thenewserver.com/logo.png

In both cases, remember to make use of proper expiration http header, to let iOS check from time to time.

By the way, as I said, your solution of checking a txt file, it's perfectly valid. But even in this case, remeber to set the expiration header on such http request, maybe with a "no cache".

Comment: Yes, I have a banner (UIImageView) that always points to a URL to `retrieve` and `set` its images from, and the URL changes from time to time. That's why I need to be able to access the URL externally, rather than the URL being hard coded into the app itself. Currently I am rather clueless of how I can implement this as I'm new to iOS development. I apologise for my ignorance in server side programming but I don't understand what a "Minimal Proxy" or a "307 redirect" is even after some googling. Could I probably utilise a **BaaS** like [Parse](https://www.parse.com/)?

Comment: added few explanation

Answer (score -1):

You can use apple's iCloud to store that URL.
Then , you can track changes using e `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification` .  You can check  [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html)